# POST call using context-path not working in spring boot 2.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, contextpath, spring-boot-2

I am migrating my spring boot application from 1.5.x to 2.x
I am getting 405 error while making POST call to context path without trailing /

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2020-11-04T12:07:19.065+0000",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Request method 'GET' not supported",
    "path": "/hello/"
}
```

below is my code

application.properties:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: hello-world-service
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /hello
  port: 8082
```

HelloWorldController.java

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class HelloWorldController {
    
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> helloWorld(@RequestBody HelloDto helloDto){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(helloDto.getName());
    }
}
```

HelloDto.java

```java
@Data
public class HelloDto {
    private String name;
}
```

spring boot version:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.11.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

When I make POST call on http://localhost:8082/test , I get 405 status below is the screenshot

[image]

But when I make POST call on http://localhost:8082/test/ , It worked fine. below is the snapshot

[image]

Is there any way to handle scenario where we make call to `localhost:8082/test` will give same result as we make a call to `localhost:8082/test/`

Comment: May `http://localhost:8082/hello/` instead of  `http://localhost:8082/test/`.

Comment: yes my issue is resolved , please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me after I added below property in application.yml

```
server:
  tomcat:
    redirect-context-root: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't endpoint `/hello` but `/hello/`. `/hello` is main/root path and your endpoint is specified for `/hello/` because of this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
```

Comment: if I remove `@RequestMapping(value = "/")` then also same behavior , and yes url is /hello I written /test by mistake

Comment: It's such how urls works in Spring Boot. `/hello` is default path and `/hello/` is your endpoint. If you want to specify an endpoint for `/hello` you need to delete `context-path: /hello` or change value to `/` and set `/hello` as value in `@RequestMapping`.